# Why am i unable to getFileName & display it in format (Word Filename Counts) In Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

The Input is a text file named Wiki-micro.txt ... The word count program is running fine .. What i need is to modify it & change its output format from (Word count) to (Word####Filename count)
I want my output in format (Word#####Filename count), Can you please let me know where i am going wrong? I used the Input Split but its not working .. Kindly, help me in that.

```
  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable ,  Text ,  Text ,  IntWritable > {
  private final static IntWritable one  = new IntWritable( 1);
  private Text word  = new Text();

  private static final Pattern WORD_BOUNDARY = Pattern .compile("\\s*\\b\\s*");

  public void map( LongWritable offset,  Text lineText,  Context context)
    throws  IOException,  InterruptedException {

     String line  = lineText.toString();
     Text currentWord  = new Text();
     InputSplit input_split = context.getInputSplit();
     String FName = ((FileSplit) input_split).getPath().getName();

     for ( String word  : WORD_BOUNDARY .split(line)) {
        if (word.isEmpty()) {
           continue;
        }
        currentWord  = new Text(word);
        context.write(currentWord, one);
        context.write(new Text(FName), one);
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Please provide more information, not just 'it's not working'. Does it compile, does it run? Does it produce any output? What is the input and expected sample output?

Comment: Thanks for replying ...
It runs .. It shows the output & the output is (Word counter) 
It does not display the filename.

Comment: The Input is a textfile named Wiki-micro.txt ...
The word count program is running fine .. What i need is to modify it & change its output format from (Word count) to (Word####Filename count).

Comment: Is mapreduce a requirement? Why not use Hive, for example?

Comment: MapReduce is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but what happens if you replace the last 3 lines:

```
        currentWord  = new Text(word);
        context.write(currentWord, one);
        context.write(new Text(FName), one);
```

with

```
        currentWord  = new Text(word + "####" + FName);
        context.write(currentWord, one);
        context.write(new Text(FName), one);
```

Comment: Nothing happens ... 
Same output ..
I don't know why is it not even concatenating "###"

Comment: Thanks brother, you were right. The issue has been resolved. Thanks again.